# Some confusion about Schauder's fixed point theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

The Schauder fixed point theorem states that if $X$ (possibly infinite-dimensional) is a Banach space, $K\subset X$ is a convex, bounded and closed subset and $T:K\rightarrow K$ is compact (nonlinear compact mapping), then $T$ has, at least, one fixed point in $K$. This result still holds if $K$ is just homeomorphic to a convex, bounded and closed subset.

I understand the proof of the first part but not the part where the results still hold if  $K$ is just homeomorphic to a convex, bounded, and closed subset. The reason is because if we have a homeomorphism $h:K\rightarrow D$, then $hTh^{-1}:D \to D$ may not necessarily be a compact mapping because homeomorphism does not always map bounded sets to bounded sets and to show the mapping is compact, we need to show the image of bounded sets is relatively compact.

Comment: While homeomorphisms do not necessarily map bounded sets to bounded sets, they do map compact sets to compact sets. But that does not help you here, does it?

Comment: According to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_fixed-point_theorem the boundedness is not required, but the assumption is that $T(K)$ is compact, therefore bounded. You can replace $K$ with the closure of the convex hull of $T(K) $ obtaining $K'$ which is bounded (I believe) and $T(K')\subset K'.$

Comment: I think "$K$ just homeomorphic to a convex, bounded and closed subset" is not enough: Let $E$ be any separable infinite dimensional Banach space. Then it is known that $E$ is homeomorphic to its closed unit Ball $B_1$. And there are compact fixed-point free mappings $f:E \to E$. For example fix $x_0$ with $\|x_0\|=1$ and set $f(x_0)=(1+\|x\|)x_0$.

Comment: What is the definition of compactness for nonlinear operators? Wikipedia requires for Schauder's fixed point theorem that $f(K)$ be compact.

Comment: @PhoemueX A common definition of compactness for nonlinear operators is that bounded subsets of the domain are mapped to relatively compact sets. In fact sometimes compact means that the image of the domain is relatively compact. In the question the first definition seems to be used.

Comment: @PhoemueX yes the definition provided by Gerd is correct. It might be easier to show that the image of a bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence usually.